# Finding the MSE Using the Delta Method

Tags: variance, bias, mse, delta-method

I don't get the step in the solution for b) can someone please fill in the missing steps between going from eqn (1) to the solution. Thanks.

Question:

[image]

Solution:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$MSE(g(\hat{p})) = \left[\text{Bias}(g(\hat{p})) \right]^2 + \text{Var}(g(\hat{p})). $$

$\text{Var}(g(\hat{p})) = E\left[(g(\hat{p}) - g(p) )^2  \right] =(1 -2p)^2 \dfrac{p(1-p)}{n},$ as solved for previously. So the only task is now to find the Bias. Bias is defined as $E\left[ g(\hat{p}) \right] - g(p)$.

By equation (1)
\begin{align*}
g(\hat{p}) - g(p)& = (\hat{p} - p)(1-2p) - (\hat{p} - p)^2 \\
& = (\hat{p} - p)(1-2p) - \text{Var}(\hat{p})\\
E\left[g(\hat{p}) - g(p) \right] & = E\left[(\hat{p} - p)(1-2p) \right] - \text{Var}(\hat{p})\\
E\left[g(\hat{p}) \right] - g(p) &= (1-2p)E\left[(\hat{p} - p) \right] - \text{Var}(\hat{p}).\\
\end{align*}

Since $E[\hat{p}] = p$ and Var$(\hat{p}) = p(1-p)/n$, we get
$$E\left[g(\hat{p}) \right] - g(p) = -\dfrac{p(1-p)}{n}. $$

This gives the desired result.

---

**EDIT:**
Since $X_i$ are independent Bernoulli with probability of success $p$, and $Var(X_i) = p(1-p)$, we have 
\begin{align*}
Var(\hat{p}) & = Var\left( \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i \right)\\
& = \dfrac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} Var(X_i)\\
& = \dfrac{p(1-p)}{n}.
\end{align*}

Comment: shouldn't the variance be p(1-p)/(n-1) dividing by n-1 instead of n or you only divide by n-1 when you are using p-hat

Comment: No, I have added a proof for the variance to illustrate why it is so.